# Non-convex optimization with quadratic constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

Let $\boldsymbol{a}=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $b,c\in \mathbb{R}$. I need to study a problem in the form

\begin{align}
\min_{\boldsymbol{x}}& \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i a_i\\
s.t.& \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i=b,\\
&\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2_i=c,\\
&\boldsymbol{x}\geq0.
\end{align}

Which is non-convex due to the quadratic equality constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x^2_i=c$.
Any chance that it is possible to rewrite it as a convex linear program? Or that maybe one can find a closed-form solution for the global minimum?
Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: could always just relax the constraint to $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \mathbf{\leq} c$, which would make it a really easy convex problem. However, that's not guaranteed to give you anything relevant to the original problem :(

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, relaxing the quadratic equality with an inequality it's not an option for me.